# Navigation Drawer Back Stack doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed, fragment-backstack

I have an app developed like the following image:

[image]

So a fragment A with a menu. Clicking on the menu it will open a fragment B.
My problem is that, when I click on the back button, nothing happens, so I can not return from fragment B to fragment A, and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentA, fragmentA.getTag()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

**Fragment A (on click on the menu)**

```
Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment, fragmentB);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**Fragment B**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            String contenuto = "*" + titolo + "*" + "\n" + desc;
            String textToShare = getResources().getString(R.string.Linc);
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", contenuto + "\n\n" + textToShare);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.sharing)));
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity

**After**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**Put**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

Comment: Where I should put it? In Main Activity or in the fragment?

Comment: In mainActivity

Comment: does it still remain at FragmentB?

Comment: Updated again, try now please

Comment: yes exactly. If I click on the back button in the Action Bar nothing happen, if I click on the back button of the phone it comes back to the fragment A.

Comment: yes, but unfortunately when I click on the back button in the Action Bar nothing happen :(

Comment: Updated Again, should work. Actually you were dealing with the navigation at two places.Thats why only back press of phone was working fine

Answer (score 0):

did you try this `onBackPressed`

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
            val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            if(manager.backStackEntryCount > 0){
                manager.popBackStack()
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```